# How do I verify that an interface VPC endpoint is functioning well?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am pretty new to AWS, and here is my scenario:
I create a sagemaker endpoint that can be called with AWS SDK IAmazonSageMakerRuntime::InvokeEndpointAsync() from a EC2 web server in a private subnet over public internet via NAT instance.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mydata)))
{
   InvokeEndpointRequest req = new InvokeEndpointRequest()
   {
      EndpointName = "MyEndpoint",
      ContentType = "application/json",
      Body = ms
   };
   var resp = await _sageMakerRuntime.InvokeEndpointAsync(req);
}
```

And to further secure the connection and avoid traffic over public internet, I set up a interface VPC endpoint(the associated security group inbound rule allows the cidr ip range in my VPC with port 80/443) for SageMakerRuntime service to take advantage of the benefits from using AWS PrivteConnection.

```
EndpointSageMakerSecurityGroup:
Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
Properties:
  GroupDescription: Enable access from app to interface VPC endpoint for sagemaker runtime
  VpcId: !Ref VPC
  SecurityGroupIngress:
  - CidrIp: 10.50.0.0/16
    IpProtocol: tcp
    ToPort: 80
    FromPort: 80
  - CidrIp: 10.50.0.0/16
    IpProtocol: tcp
    ToPort: 443
    FromPort: 443
  Tags:
  - Key: Name
    Value: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-EndpointSageMakerSecurityGroup"

EndpointSageMakerRuntime:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: '*'
            Action:
              - sagemaker:InvokeEndpoint
            Resource: !Sub arn:${AWS::Partition}:sagemaker:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:endpoint/MyEndpoint      
      SubnetIds: !Ref PrivateSubnets
      SecurityGroupIds:
      - !Ref EndpointSageMakerSecurityGroup
      ServiceName: !Sub com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.sagemaker.runtime #runtime.sagemaker.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com
      PrivateDnsEnabled: true
      VpcEndpointType: Interface
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
```

However, I really have no idea whether the interface VPC endpoint does take effect and my function call InvokeEndpointAsync() indeed calls to the interface VPC endpoint into AWS SageMakerRuntime service. I tried creating a notification in the interface VPC endpoint to publish message to a SNS topic and subscribing that SNS topic with my email, but I was not able to get any email from it. I guess there is something wrong but can't not figure out how to get the interface VPC endpoint right. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried looking up in CloudTrail logs?

Comment: Just tried but couldn't find anything useful..

Comment: try launching two EC2 machines one with in VPC and another outside of it. Then check the SSH connectivity from EC2 web server to see if it is not accessible from internet

Comment: EC2 web server is accessible from internet and can also access the sagemaker endpoint over public internet through NAT. So maybe I should tear down NAT and see if EC2 web server can still call into sagemaker runtime service via the interface VPC endpoint? But removing NAT is sort of too risky..

Comment: Have you enabled VPC DNSHostnames and DNSSupport?

Comment: Yes, I have both EnableDnsSupport: true and EnableDnsHostnames: true.